# Django ModelForm failing with the same error after first error

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this weird situation with Django ModelForm.

Whenever I'm submitting a correct modelform in Django FOR THE FIRST TIME, I have no problem.

But whenever I FIRST fill an incorrect form, get the error from the is_valid() and try to redo the previously CORRECT form, it shows the same exact error (Product with this Title already exists.)
Although I enter a different title (it keeps the previous error)

Thanks for your help.

```
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # Basic form validation: Checking what to submit with the model. Type checking (see the the schema is enforced)

        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('single_product', args=(product.slug,)))
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    return render_to_response("products/add.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It looks like this happens after parsley custom validation has errors, and after I correct the errors and send the forms, they kind of "stay"

Form is here:

```
@parsleyfy
class ProductForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'file')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.disable_csrf = True
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(Field('file'), css_class='col-md-4'),
                Div(Field('title'), css_class='col-md-9'),
                Div(Field('description'), css_class='col-md-12'),
                Div(Field(PrependedText('price', '$')), css_class='col-md-7'),
                'preview',
                'screenshot',
                css_class='row',
                )
        )
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to show the code for the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

This means that products with different title already exists too.

Your view code is old-fashioned but correct and should work as expected.

Comment: I just noticed that if I deactive django-parsley, the issue disappears.
This is the custom checking code I get.

Maybe you can see some error there?

        var checkInput = function () {
            instance = $('#product').parsley();
            if (instance.isValid()) {
                var file = document.getElementById('id_file').files[0];
            }
        }